# Multivariate RNN/LSTM architecture for optimizing one input variable

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Let $x = [x_1, x_2, x_3]$ and $y = y$ where all variables in $x$ correlates highly with $y$ and there could also be some crosscorrelation within the set of variables in $x$.

The data takes the form of a sequence/timeseries.
i.e for each timestep we have three independent variables and one dependent or one independent variable and three dependent depending on how we structure it. So the whole timeseries would be X = [x1, x2, x3, ...xn] and Y = [y1, y2, y3, ....yn]

$x_1$ for timestep h1 could be highly influential for the output y in timestep h2-hn. I want to construct an LSTM that captures all variables and feed it to a blackbox optimization which configures ONE of the variables in $x$ lets say $x_2$ for maximizing the expected output y in the future timesteps(one timestep in the future is sufficient).

Note that for an future timestep I cannot see or configure the two other variables I do not want to optimize. So maybe the notation $x=x$ and $y=[y_1, y_2, y_3]$ would capture this better, if we flip it like this I want to optimize $x$ in the blackbox optimization to maximize e.g $y_1$.

My first idea is to construct some sort of many-to-many network where the variable I want to optimize in the blackbox optimization would be the sole input in each timestep and then output the second two variables in $x$ and $y$, then this output has to be passed on to the cells in the second timestep.

My goal is to feed the network to a black box optimizer in which i configure one of the variables with the goal to maximize one of the other variables.

How would one go about this architecture?
Does anynone see any issues about this? is there a smarter way to tackle this?

As for the baseline I just construct a feed forward neural network which does not adhere to the sequence but solely rely on the current state and predict an output. But since it is a timeseries with seasons, trends etc i should be able to outperform it, I just have to wrap my head around the multiple output/an appropriate architecture. Does anyone have some input on this architecture or does anyone have some idea on how to go on about this problem?

Comment: "variable would be the sole input in each timestep and then output the second two variables in x and y, then this output has to be passed on to the cells in the second timestep": can you explain how that is different from a normal rnn architecture?

Comment: @hH1sG0n3 it isnt, thats exactly why i chose an RNN/LSTM architecture instead of an normal feed forward.. to capture the autocorrelation. The big question for me is how i would structure it, i could also have 3 input variables and just predict the y, the issue there is when i feed it to the blackbox i have to generate/extrapolate the two other variables or leave them as zero and just use the weight that got generated for the variable i can configure... maybe that would work... but i have an feeling there is a way smarter way of doing this

Comment: Thanks for more details. Can I ask why do you "have to generate/extrapolate the two other variables"? IS there a reason you cannot just use one sequence input $X = [x1, ..., xn]$?

Comment: @hH1sG0n3 thanks for your input! i want to capture the correlation between the two other variables i cant configure and y but due to the crosscorrelation it might be unnecessary do add those dimensions... it might be the case that an high e.g x1 value in timestep 1 have a high correlation with an high value y in timestep h4 even though the variable i can configure and want to optimize doesnt have that exact correlation.

Comment: Ok thanks. if you amend your post above so that there is a clear description of (a) what exactly your input looks like (e.g. 3 different sequences) (b) what is your end goal is (e.g. classification) we may be able to help you further.

Comment: @hH1sG0n3 sorry for the horrible explanation, i now edited it(the top part) so hopefully it is a little bit more clear